# BigCommerce - change thank you text on order confirmation page in StencilJS theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using StencilJS powered template for BigCommerce store and am having trouble editing the thank you text on order confirmation page.

The checkout.html and order_confirmation.html pages use {{checkout.order_confirmation_content}} to display the content which also includes a heading and a few buttons.

I think I might be missing something essential.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I might have asked this question in a hurry, I stumbled onto the following link :

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/template-files/customize-stencil-checkout/multi-language-checkout#json

So, there is a JSON file that they have with what they call "hidden translation keys". 
So those keys or key-value pairs need to be copied into the main JSON file and that's the solution.